# Deallocate Popover in Safari Extension

Tags: memory-management, safari, popover

I am developing Safari extension in which I have created Popover dyanmically and attached to toolbar item.  Now I want to deallocate this popover but its not working.

I have used below code :

```js
var item = safari.extension.toolbarItems[0];

if(item.popover != null)
{

    popId = item.popover.identifier;

    item.popover.hide();

    item.popover = null;
}

safari.extension.removePopover(prevPopId);
```

but this code is not deallocating to popover.
Next time when I am creating popover with same id, I am getting exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove popover by popover identifier safari.extension.removePopover("popover_identifier");

In your case safari.extension.removePopover(popId);